# Statistical test for SPSS comparing a change in attitude using a Likert scale

Tags: spss

I have two questions both with Likert-type scale (1 through 4) that gauges the attitude change between question 1 and question 2.

For example,

Q1

```
In 2021 how worried were you about driving an electric vehicle?
1 - Not worried at all
2 - A little worried
3 - Worried
4 - Extremely worried
```

Q2

```
In 2022, how worried were you about driving an electric vehicle?
1 - Not worried at all
2 - A little worried
3 - Worried
4 - Extremely worried
```

What would be the ideal test to use to illustrate the change in attitude between 2021 and 2022?

Thank you

Comment: Have you recorded the data such that you can identify the answer for Q1 and Q2 for the same individual ?  If so, you want to use an approach that takes into account repeated measures or paired data.  An ideal approach is ordinal regression.  If SPSS is capable, ordinal regression can account for repeated measures with a mixed effects model (fixed and random effects).

Comment: P.S. These terms are somewhat nebulous, but I wouldn't use the term "*scale*" for single questions.  I would call these "*Likert-type items*" or "*Likert-type questions*".

Comment: Yes, definitely Likert-type items. Each data row has a variable for Q1 and a variable for Q2, where Q1 and Q2 will store a result of 1, 2, 3, or 4 to represent the ordinal level of worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data are arranged in rows in wide format, I'll assume that each row represents a respondent, and the data are paired this way.

For Likert-type items, especially with only four options, it's best to treat the data as ordinal (categorical ordinal).  That is, they are not interval or really numerical.  We know that e.g. 4 > 3, but we don't know if the distance between "Not worried at all" and "A little worried" is the same as the distance between "A little worried" and "Worried".

Probably the ideal approach is to use ordinal regression.  Because the data are paired you will probably want to treat *Respondent* as a random variable (in a mixed effects model, or "hierarchical regression").  I don't know if this is available in SPSS.

A simpler approach is to use a paired sample sign test, though this approach may be less powerful than using ordinal regression.

Note that some other common tests for paired data treat the data as numeric.  These include paired *t*-test and Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was also considering the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. For the distance between attitudes, how would one define that the distances are evenly spread apart? Or does it not apply to the tests we are considering?

Comment: If you *want to* assume that the categories are evenly spaced, there may be an option in the software for ordinal regression to make this assumption † , or you could use a test that makes this assumption, like the Wilcoxon signed rank test.
_____
† For example in the *ordinal* package in R, you can set the spacing of the categories to be equal or to be symmetrical (but not necessarily equal).